# Is TStringList thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tstringlist

Is it ok to read data from TStringList without any form of synchronization? For example synchronization with main thread.

Example code

```
var MyStringList:TStringList; //declared globally

procedure TForm1.JvThread1Execute(Sender: TObject; Params: Pointer);
var x:integer;
begin

   for x:=0 to MaxInt do MyStringList.Add(FloatToStr(Random));  

end;


procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var x:integer;
   SumOfRandomNumbers:double;
begin

  for x:=0 to MyStringList.Count-1 do
    SumOfRandomNumbers:=SumOfRandomNumbers+StrToFloat(MyStringList.Strings[x]);

end;
```

or Should I protect access to MyStringList with EnterCiticalSection

```
var MyStringList:TStringList; //declared globally

procedure TForm1.JvThread1Execute(Sender: TObject; Params: Pointer);
var x:integer;
begin

   for x:=0 to MaxInt do 
   begin
     EnterCriticalSection(MySemaphore); 
     MyStringList.Add(FloatToStr(Random));  
     LeaveCriticalSection(MySemaphore);
   end;

end;


procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var x:integer;
   SumOfRandomNumbers:double;
begin

  for x:=0 to MyStringList.Count-1 do
  begin

     EnterCriticalSection(MySemaphore);
     SumOfRandomNumbers:=SumOfRandomNumbers+StrToFloat(MyStringList.Strings[x]);
     LeaveCriticalSection(MySemaphore);

  end;

end;
```

Comment: You must always protect memory that can be written and read by the same time. In your case, the main thread can read and the secondary thread can write, so yes you need to synchronize.

Comment: How could it possibly be? The compiler would have to read your mind. Add synchronisation.

Answer (score 16):

First, no `TStringList` is not thread-safe.
Second, attempting to make it so would be a terrible idea for a low-level container that in the vast majority of cases would not be shared across multiple threads.
Third, the naive code you propose to make it thread-safe is woefully insufficient. It falls well short of making it truly thread-safe - which is part of the problem in trying to do so generically.

In the text of your question you ask:

> Is it ok to read data from TStringList without any form of synchronisation?

Yes it is okay. In fact, that is preferred because it is more efficient.

***However***, if the data is shared *across threads*, you may run into problems. Which is why you should minimise the amount of data (not just string lists) shared across threads. And if you do **need** to share data, do so in a suitably controlled fashion.

---

## Expanding on point 3

The reason your code is not thread-safe is that it falls short of protecting ***all*** your data from shared access. This is a common misunderstanding in multi-threaded development: "*I just need to wrap certain operations with locks and all will be fine.*"

The point is, if your list is shared, you are:

- Sharing the structures that represent the container.
- **AND** you are sharing the data members (the actual strings) themselves.
- When dealing with strings, this goes a step further, because the way Delphi manages strings means they could be shared (through internal reference counting) with other strings of the same value in an entirely different area of the application.

While it is possible your proposed locking strategy *might* be suitable for your *current* requirements, it is far from being generally thread-safe.

## Conclusion

If you want to write thread-safe code the **onus is on you** to:

- Understand the data access paths.
- Minimise sharing between threads (by far the best bang for buck).
- And to implement the best strategy to share the data safely (of which there are many options, and locking is not guaranteed to be best in any case).

---

## Sidenote

I indicated earlier that your locking technique only "*might be suitable for your current requirements*" because I do not believe you have really given an indication as to you ***real*** requirements. If you have then you *really do need to take note of the following*:

In the code you have presented there would be absolutely no benefit in making your `TStringList` "thread-safe". You populate the list in a loop, and you read values in a second loop. You're doing absolutely nothing to use the data *concurrently*.

The closest your code should come to multi-threading is: *It would be a good idea to process both loops off the main thread to avoid blocking the UI*. In which case, the background thread should **NOT** share its `TStringList` instance. And can simply synchronise with the main thread to report the result (and possibly progress updates).

By not *sharing* data that doesn't ***need*** to be shared, you can bypass the need for locks entirely. They would be an *unnecessary* overhead. And you can be happy that `TStringList` *doesn't* have a built-in "thread-safety" mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. There is no mechanism inside of `TStringList`, that locks for example `.Add()` or `.GetStrings()`.

Unfortunately there is nothing built in like `TThreadList`, that is a threadsafe wrapper for `TList`. But you could build that easily on your own.

Here is a simple example for a synchronized *decorator* of TStringList, in that I cover the case for `Add()`:

```
TThreadStringList = class
private
  FStringList: TStringList;
  FCriticalSection: TRtlCriticalSection;
  // ...
public 
  function Add(const S: string): Integer;
  // ...
end;

// ...

TThreadStringList.Add(const S: string): Integer;
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(FCriticalSection);
  try
    Result:= Add(S);
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(FCriticalSection);
  end;
end;
```

It should be easy, to apply this to all other methods you need.

Bear in mind, that you have to *initialize* the critical section, before you can *use* it, and to delete it *afterwards*.

Comment: The critical section based code in the question places the lock in the wrong place.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I added an example to clarify that.

Comment: Still won't work. You can't just lock each method and make all code threadsafe.

Comment: Why not? I would not advise to lock each(!) method. But to provide an interface for those methods that really need to be locked, depending on the use case. Here it would be `Add()`, `SetStrings()`, `GetStrings()` for example.

Comment: Because some operations that you need to be atomic can span multiple method calls. Internal sync for a complex type is seldom viable. Generally the usage determines the appropriate sync strategy.