# Using threads in firemonkey frames

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

There is a main form, when you click on the button, a frame is loaded into the form.

Button code:

```
procedure TMain.ButtonObjectsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TFrameSystems.Execute(LayoutMain,
  procedure(Frame: TFrameSystems)
  begin
    // DoSomething
  end,
  procedure(Frame: TFrameSystems; Success: Boolean)
  begin
    // DoSomething
  end);
end;
```

Frame:

```
  ...

  TKey = class
    public
      S: string;
      constructor Create(const AStr: string);
  end;

  TFrameSystems = class(TFrameOverlay)
    ...
  private
    ...
    FProcCallback: TProc<TFrameSystems, Boolean>;
    FActiveUser: TUser;
    procedure UpdateBuildingList;
    ...
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    class procedure Execute(AParent: TControl; ProcSet: TProc<TFrameSystems>; ProcExecuted: TProc<TFrameSystems, Boolean>);
    property ActiveUser: TUser read FActiveUser write FActiveUser;
    ...
    { Public declarations }
  end;
implementation


uses 
 ...
{$R *.fmx}

class procedure TFrameSystems.Execute(AParent: TControl; ProcSet: TProc<TFrameSystems>;
  ProcExecuted: TProc<TFrameSystems, Boolean>);
begin
  var Frame := TFrameSystems.Create(AParent);
  Frame.Parent := AParent;
  Frame.FProcCallback := ProcExecuted;
  Frame.Align := TAlignLayout.Contents;
  Frame.BringToFront;
  if Assigned(ProcSet) then
    ProcSet(Frame);
end;

constructor TFrameSystems.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Name := '';
  FActiveUser := ClientModule.User;
  UpdateBuildingList;
end;

procedure TFrameSystems.UpdateBuildingList;
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  var
    s1: TStrings;
    JSONObject: TJSONObject;
    i: integer;
  begin
    JSONObject := ClientModule.ServerMethodsClient.RefreshUserBuildingList(ActiveUser.id);
    ActiveUser.RefreshBuildingList(JSONObject);
    s1 := TStringList.Create;
    for I := 0 to ActiveUser.BuldingList.Count - 1 do
    begin
    with cb_object_list.Items do
      AddObject(ActiveUser.BuldingList[I].Name, TKey.Create(IntToStr(ActiveUser.BuldingList[I].id)));
      s1.AddObject(ActiveUser.BuldingList[I].Kks, TIntObj.Create(ActiveUser.BuldingList[I].id));
    end;
    Edit1.AssignItems(s1);
  end).Start;

end;
```

When the frame opens, I need to upload some data to the combobox. If you call the UpdateBuildingList function and do it without a thread, then the program freezes for a while.

I tried to solve the problem by adding an anonymous thread to this function and it seems like the problem is solved. However, why does it work without TThread.Synchronize and in general, did I do the right thing by creating an anonymous thread?

Comment: You may just have been lucky so far that it hasn't caused a problem

Comment: @DaveNottage In fact, I have assumptions that one day something will go wrong, but at the moment, no matter how much I tried to run the program, there were no problems.

Comment: Ah well, if you know it's wrong, but can't get it to crash, I guess you should just carry on doing what you know to be wrong. No, that doesn't sound right at all ......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To be honest, I'm still wondering how to do the right thing and move away from bad practices. And I would be very grateful to someone who could explain my mistake to me and guide me to find the right solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are populating your ComboBox from secondary thread item by item which is not allowed and could lead to various problems.

I also see you are using `AddObject` in order to add object to each ComboBox item.

You should do this in a different way that is tread safe. How?

First create yourself a new string list and populate it using `AddObject` like you populate your combo box now. You can freely do this in secondary thread.

Once you have done that simply assign your StringList to your `ComboBox.Items` property. You do this within `Synchronize` so that it is done within main thread.

Here is  a quick code example:

```
//Populate StringList with strings and connected objects
SL := TStringList.Create;
SL.AddObject('Panel1',Panel1);
SL.AddObject('Panel2',Panel2);
//Assign StringList to ComboBox.Items property
//This can be done since TStringList is actually descendant class from 
//TStrings which is the property type of ComboBox.Items property
ComboBox1.Items := SL;
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I can still leave an anonymous thread, fill in a StringList in it and call TThread.Synchronize as follows:  `TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure begin ComboBox1.Items := SL; end);`

Comment: Yes provided that your anonymous thread will be the only one accessing the said string list while populating its data. String list on itself is still not thread-safe so you still need to limit simultaneous access to to only one thread. You can read more about `TStringList` thread safety in [Is TStringList thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38807135/3636228)

Comment: thanks you so much for the useful information and help in solving the question.